# INSERT statement cannot contain a SELECT statement -sql server2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-insert

```
    declare @us table(name nvarchar(100),lastname nvarchar(100),UID bigint,available bit);
        declare
        @Name nvarchar(100),
        @lastname nvarchar(100),
        @UID bigint,
        @Avail bit

        insert into @us
        select @name=name,@lastname=lastname,@UID=UID,@Avail=available from Users where available='1'
 select * from @us
```

I got this error

> An INSERT statement cannot contain a SELECT statement that assigns
>   values to a variable.

I searched for this problem but many people used queries like this and they said *there is no problem*!  i'm using sql server 2012, is it a deference between MSSQL2012 and MSSQL2008? and what is the best solution if I want to return a table from my Stored Procedures? what is wrong in my query?

Comment: Why not just assign to variables first, and insert using variables later? Also, is it guaranteed that exactly 1 row is returned by the `select` query?

Comment: What are you expecting this to do if more than one row in `Users` has `available` equal to 1?

Comment: @shree.pat18 , yes, this is my another problem, some times result is more that one row! what I have to do?

Comment: Why do you need the variables exactly? From this snippet of code I do not see their use.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what in is the solution in this case?

Comment: Um, we can't *both* ask each other what the expected behaviour is in a particular scenario. I'm asking you what you *expect* to happen in this case. I don't know what the "solution" is because you haven't told me what you'd expect.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I expect To find the users where they are 'Available', so it can be 0 row, 1 row or more than one rows. this query is in a store procedure I want to have table as a result. i don't want to send single parameters. I need a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information provided in the question, the variables seem to be unnecessary. You can directly do `INSERT...SELECT` like so:

```
declare @us table(name nvarchar(100),lastname nvarchar(100),UID bigint,available bit);

insert into @us
select name,lastname,UID,available 
from Users 
where available='1'

select * from @us
```

Comment: I do this but it Didn't work before your answer! now it's working well! i'm so confused, but thank you so much..

Answer (score 1):

Alternate and complex way of doing the same task is the below one. Hope nobody likes this. Just I am showing we have one more alternative way.

```
declare @us table(name nvarchar(100),lastname nvarchar(100),UID bigint,available bit);
declare @Name nvarchar(100), @lastname nvarchar(100), @UID bigint,@Avail bit

DECLARE ALLRECORDS CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT name,lastname,UID,available from Users where available='1'

     OPEN ALLRECORDS
     FETCH NEXT FROM ALLRECORDS INTO @Name,@lastname,@UID,@Avail

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @us    
        SELECT @Name,@lastname,@UID,@Avail 

        FETCH NEXT FROM ALLRECORDS INTO @Name,@lastname,@UID,@Avail
        END
CLOSE ALLRECORDS
DEALLOCATE ALLRECORDS
SELECT * FROM @us
```