# Insert Into Select stored procedure not working inserting NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert-into, select-into

My first time creating a stored procedure here please go easy on me. I was trying to `SELECT` my data from Table 1 (`EmpTBL`), then `INSERT` it into Table 2 (`EventTBL`)

I think the culprit is this line right here:

```
@Ename varchar(250) = NULL, 
@Edate varchar(250) = NULL,
```

I think my logic is in the right direction I just dont why it doesn't work.

Not sure what to do next.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spBdayEmp
   (@Ename varchar(250) = NUll,
    @Edate varchar(250)= NUll,
    @Etype varchar(250)  = 'Bday')
AS 
    INSERT INTO EventTBL(EventName, EventDate, EventType)
    VALUES (@Ename, @Edate, @Etype)

    SELECT
        @Ename =  (Ename + ' ' + Lname),    
        @Edate =  DATEADD(YY, DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(YYYY,dateOfBirth), dateOfBirth) 
    FROM 
        EmpTBL   
    WHERE  
        DATEADD( Year, DATEPART( Year, GETDATE()) - DATEPART( Year, DateOfBirth), DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE() + 30);
```

how would i get the values for? @Ename, @Edate?

i would like the result of the SELECT query "Ename + ' ' + Lname," equals to "@Ename" and " DATEADD(YY, DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(YYYY,dateOfBirth), dateOfBirth)," equals to "@Edate"?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: And also: how do you **call** this stored procedure? What **values** are you passing in to the parameters?

Comment: i am just testing it first in the sql server management studio to see if it works before i call it in my asp.net VB project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading [INSERT statement cannot contain a SELECT statement -sql server2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132481/insert-statement-cannot-contain-a-select-statement-sql-server2012)

i realized i had it all wrong so after some experimenting i finally found a solution.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spBdayEmp
AS INSERT INTO 
EventTBL SELECT  (Ename + ' ' + Lname), DATEADD(YY, DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(YYYY,dateOfBirth), dateOfBirth),('Bday')FROM 
EmpTBL WHERE DATEADD( Year, DATEPART( Year, GETDATE()) - DATEPART( Year, DateOfBirth), DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE() + 30);
```

Thanks for everyone who's been trying to help out!

Answer (score 0):

You do your insert before you have selected values into your variables.

And anothet consideration - how will your code handle returning 2 or more results from your select?

You may be better using a pattern like;

```
Insert into table2 select values from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope you have only 3 columns in EventTBL table. please update your query as below:

please change your query as below and then try

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spBdayEmp
AS 
INSERT INTO EventTBL(EventName, EventDate, EventType)
SELECT
    @Ename =  (Ename + ' ' + Lname),    
    @Edate =  DATEADD(YY, DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(YYYY,dateOfBirth), dateOfBirth) ,'Bday'
FROM 
    EmpTBL   
WHERE  
    DATEADD( Year, DATEPART( Year, GETDATE()) - DATEPART( Year, DateOfBirth), DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE() + 30);
```

Comment: im getting this error mr. singh "Must declare the scalar variable "@Ename"."

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spBdayEmp
       (@Etype varchar(250)  = 'Bday')
    AS 
        INSERT INTO EventTBL(EventName, EventDate, EventType)
        SELECT
            Ename + ' ' + Lname,    
            DATEADD(YY, DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(YYYY,dateOfBirth), dateOfBirth),
            @Etype 
        FROM 
            EmpTBL   
        WHERE  
            DATEADD( Year, DATEPART( Year, GETDATE()) - DATEPART( Year, DateOfBirth), DateOfBirth) BETWEEN CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE() + 30);
```

**Note:** I see you have used `@Etype` parameter to the SP and assigned some default values to it. When executing the SP You can't pass `@Etype`if you want the default to get used.

Comment: i intentionaly set tthe @Etype value as 'Bday'  as a Default

Comment: how would i get the values for? @Ename, @Edate? i would like the result of this " Ename + ' ' + Lname," equals to "@Ename" and " DATEADD(YY, DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(YYYY,dateOfBirth), dateOfBirth)," equals to "@Edate"?

Comment: To get the values you can use the below in `SELECT` statement - 
`@Ename =  (Ename + ' ' + Lname)    
 @Edate =  DATEADD(YY, DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) -  DATEPART(YYYY,dateOfBirth), dateOfBirth)`
But remember to use these values for `INSERT`, you need to use the `INSERT` after the `SELECT` is done.